# CasperJS scraping foiled by <noscript> tag

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, noscript

I'm using CasperJS to scrape a website.  The page source has a `<noscript>` tag, and therefore is not showing the page I need to scrape, because it claims I don't have JavaScript enabled.

`javascriptEnabled` is `true` by default in CasperJS, but I added it to my initialization anyway, to no avail.

Any work arounds to fix this issue?  It might also be an issue with PhantomJS...

Comment: Can you provide a site where you see this behavior? What PhantomJS version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this issue has been fixed -- I did the following, if anyone has any questions.  The HTML was rendered by the JavaScript, which took a long time to load, so open it like you would normally in a browser, and find an element that only appears when the javascript loads -- note doing view source doesn't work you have to inspect element (you get current DOM).

I then did:

```
casper.waitForSelector('.SOME_CLASS', function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML('.SOME_CLASS'));
    this.echo(this.getElementInfo('.SOME_CLASS').text);
});
```

This allows the page to stop and load the javascript.